# jQuery Sortable drag elements from one container to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

My intended goal is to have two separate containers next to each other. The left container will contain a big list of draggable elements. The right container will contain several corresponding fixed height and width blocks which the elements on the left can be dragged into.

I kind of have this working right now but it is very buggy and quite frankly does not work nicely. I made a container called `drop` that has several `divs` inside of it that are disabled from being sortable. However I had to insert a nested `div` inside of the disabled div so that I could actually drag objects into each block. I can actually increase the usability quite a bit by giving the `sub-container` (the nested div inside of the disabled div` a height and width.

Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ycnux2Lo/1/) to see what I mean. (Note: the blocks on the right should be able to accept multiple elements. Example: `bullets` on the right should be able to have `bullet1, bullet2 and bullet3` from the left dragged into it.)

Hope this makes sense.

Here is some code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="origin" class="fbox"></div>
    <div id="drop" class="fbox"></div>
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var origin = document.getElementById('origin');
var drop = document.getElementById('drop');
var listOf = ['sku', 'product-name', 'category', 'short-description', 'description', 'price'];
var firstRow = ['sku', 'product-name', 'category', 'short-description', 'description', 'price'];
for (var y in listOf) {

    var newSub = document.createElement('div');
    newSub.setAttribute('class', 'sub-container');
    newSub.id = listOf[y];

    var newBlock = document.createElement('div');

    newBlock.setAttribute('class', 'ui-state-disabled field-container');
    newBlock.innerHTML = listOf[y];
    newBlock.appendChild(newSub);
    drop.appendChild(newBlock);
}

for (var i in firstRow) {
    if (firstRow[i] != null) {
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.id = i;
        newDiv.setAttribute('class', 'draggable');
        newDiv.innerHTML = firstRow[i];
        origin.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
}

$("#origin").sortable({
    connectWith: "#drop"
});
$("#origin div").disableSelection();
$("#drop").sortable({
    connectWith: "#origin",
    items: "div:not(.ui-state-disabled)"
});
```

Comment: It's not really clearly to me what the specific problem is, or what the desired behavior you've been unable to implement is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand your problem and I suggest you set a class name for all the linked `sortable` boxes. Its as simple as that the rest is just CSS.

Take a look: [**JSnippet DEMO**](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/317/Sortabble-with-several-groups)

jQuery:

```
$(function(){

  $('.sortme').sortable({
        connectWith: '.sortme'
  }).disableSelection();

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id='elePool' class='sortme'>
  <div>Pizza</div>
  <div>Fiat</div>
  <div>Jeep</div>
  <div>Cat</div>
  <div>Dog</div>
</div>
<div id='eleGroups'>
  <div class='sortme group group-food'></div>
  <div class='sortme group group-cars'></div>
  <div class='sortme group group-animals'></div>
</div>
```